# Solving a Differential Equation using Euler's Method of Factoring Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to solve the following differential equation using Euler's technique of factoring the characteristic polynomial given that a solution is $y=e^x$. $${y}^{\prime\prime\prime}-6y^{\prime\prime}+11y^\prime-6y$$

I found the characteristic equation: $r^3-6r^2+11r-6=0$. This equation factors to $(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)=0$. Therefore, the factors are $r_1=3,r_2=2,r_3=1$. Where can I go from here?

Based on what I saw (using Paul's Notes) I would now need to set up a system of equations based on the equation $y\left( t \right) = {c_1}{{\bf{e}}^{3t}} + {c_2}{{\bf{e}}^{2t}} + {c_3}{{\bf{e}}^{t}}$. But, without being given any other information, how can I solve for the three constants?

Comment: You can't determine the constants here. Any combination of constants gives a valid solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see :) So my answer is just the equation with the $c_1,c_2,c_3$ in it?

Comment: Yes exactly  your solution is correct. With the constants.